# Spring batch job does not start in dev environment

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring spring-boot-starter-batch 2.7.9 with mysql DB as the datasource. I have this weird problem that the batch jobs are working in my local but it fails to start in dev environment (kubernetes) with an exception like below:

```
Exception while starting job
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [3098]; The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.
```

The jobs are triggered through a rest end api which supply two job parameters a string and a datetime.

Sample params:

```
{
    "idType" : "ALL",
    "triggerTime": "2023-03-16T19:54:18.262Z" 
}
```

The one difference between my local db and dev db can be the replication factor. Dev db has 3 replicas configured whereas in local I have only one. Can this be the reason for this exception? How can i get around this one? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the definitions of the Spring Batch meta tables such that every table has a primary key.

By default, MySQL accepts tables without a primary key. But in any setup with MySQL replication, tables without primary keys either don't work at all (as in your case with group replication) or will lead to operational headaches down the road.

The root cause is that the DDLs for the Spring Batch schemas contain a very limited number of indexes. This is on purpose as the best approach to indexing depends strongly on the particular use case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.8/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#recommendationsForIndexingMetaDataTables

Comment: thanks for your answer. Looks like this is the issue. But the link you've provided does not have any suggestions for the table "BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS" where I am facing the issue. Would you recommend to add a PK(OB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME) for this table?

Comment: Using `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` and `KEY_NAME` is one option. The other option is to add an additional integer column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and make this new column the primary key. Both options should work well.